# splot axis or border description

Tags: gnuplot

in the following code I try to achieve the following:

1) As can be seen, the description 'talkative' does not appear. Is this really the `y2axis`? Or does `y2axis` not account for `splot` but only for `plot`?
Or do I have to label a `border` ?

2) How do I get tics only at the axis of interest?

3) A small detail: A close look reveals that the blue dot is transparent, but not the red and green dot. How to also make the blue dot filled?

```
set ticslevel 0

set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]
set zrange [0:1]

set object 1 polygon from \
  0, 0, 1 to \
  0, 1, 0 to \
  1, 0, 0 to \
  0, 0, 1

set view 56, 77

set style line 1 lc rgb "blue" pt 7 ps 2
set style line 2 lc rgb "red" pt 7 ps 2
set style line 3 lc rgb "green" pt 7 ps 2

unset xtics
unset ytics
unset ztics

set border 1+2+16

set xlabel "listening"  offset +4,0
set y2label "talkative"
set zlabel "sleeping" rotate offset -1,-2

splot \
  '-' with points ls 1 title "",\
  '-' with points ls 2 title "",\
  '-' with points ls 3 title ""
    1 0 0
    e
    0 1 0
    e
    0 0 1
    e
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not a solution, but some explanations:

1. Yes, `splot` doesn't have an `x2` and `y2` equivalent. You can set a ylabel and shift it:

   ```
   set ylabel 'talkative' offset graph -1.5
   ```
2. You mean getting tics only at the 'talkative' axis? That isn't possible out-of-the-box. You can have tics only on the y-axis (which gnuplot selects to always the the one in the front), or on both front and back y-axis.
3. That seems to be a bug to me. Usually you can set the border to be behind everything with `set border back`, but that doesn't work in this situation (tested with 4.6.5 and 5.0RC2). And it's also strange that it involves only one axis.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are no second axes for splots. You can see this when you rotate the plot with the mouse: The drawn border, the tics and the label are jumping from one side to the other. You can also see the intention: If the volume is quite full of plot data, the axes in the rear would be hidden by your plots. So as soon as this can happen, gnuplot switches to axes in the front. There seems to be no way around.

   (btw: when drawing the full border box, you have 4 axes in each direction. And there is definitively no y3tics or y4tics...)
2. `set xtics nomirror`
3. It's not really transparent, as only the "front border" is visible on the dot. The other lines (and also tick labels) are behind the dot. `set border back` should help, but it doesn't. The setting has an effect only for `plot` , not for `splot`. The data is plottet between front and rear axes, and so, the data hides the rear axes, but the front axes are drawn in front of the data.

In general, this all makes sense, but for special cases, there are options to tweak the plot as you want. However, only for `plot` ...